# why my followning sql query doesnt work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select 
    'N' as Content,  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  ) as [Sample Analyzed ],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,D) between 0.0005 and 0.75) as [Very Low],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,D) between 0.76 and 1.25 ) as [Low] 
union  
    select 'P' as Content,  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  ) as [Sample Analyzed ],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,C) between 0.0005 and 0.75) as [Very Low],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,C) between 0.76 and 1.25 ) as [Low] 
union  
    select 'K' as Content,  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  ) as [Sample Analyzed ],
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,B) between 0.0005 and 0.75) as [Very Low],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,B) between 0.76 and 1.25 ) as [Low] 
union  
    select 'OC' as Content,  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  ) as [Sample Analyzed ],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,A) between 0.0005 and 0.75) as [Very Low],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,A) between 0.76 and 1.25 ) as [Low]
ORDER BY
    (
     CASE 
       WHEN  Content = 'N' THEN 0
       WHEN  Content = 'P' THEN 1
       WHEN  Content = 'K' THEN 2
       WHEN  Content = 'OC' THEN 3
       ELSE 4
     END
    )
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work"? What errors do you get? What is the expected output? Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Get_NPK_Report, Line 44
Invalid column name 'Content'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Get_NPK_Report, Line 44
Invalid column name 'Content'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Get_NPK_Report, Line 44
Invalid column name 'Content'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Get_NPK_Report, Line 44
Invalid column name 'Content'.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Get_NPK_Report, Line 50
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: above error i got in  sql serve r2008      my output now   K 7 0 1
N 7 1 1
OC 7 0 0
P 7 0 2   what i want     i want order of  K,N,OC,P should be like N,P,K,OC

Comment: Ok? The error is clear and I've given a way to circumvent it.

Comment: Please note that additional information that is important to understand the problem, should be included in the question itself, not in the comment section. You can always [edit] your question and add the information in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...Invalid column name 'Content'....

That's because you can't use a column alias in the `ORDER BY`

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement
>   contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator

That's because the column alias isn't part of the select, same as above. It isn't an actual column (yet)

Here's an example by wrapping it in a `CTE`.

```
with cte as(
select 
    'N' as Content,  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  ) as [Sample Analyzed ],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,D) between 0.0005 and 0.75) as [Very Low],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,D) between 0.76 and 1.25 ) as [Low] 
union  
    select 'P' as Content,  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  ) as [Sample Analyzed ],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,C) between 0.0005 and 0.75) as [Very Low],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,C) between 0.76 and 1.25 ) as [Low] 
union  
    select 'K' as Content,  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  ) as [Sample Analyzed ],
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,B) between 0.0005 and 0.75) as [Very Low],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,B) between 0.76 and 1.25 ) as [Low] 
union  
    select 'OC' as Content,  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  ) as [Sample Analyzed ],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,A) between 0.0005 and 0.75) as [Very Low],  
    (select COUNT(*)  from TB1  where convert(float,A) between 0.76 and 1.25 ) as [Low]
)

select * from cte 
ORDER BY
    (
     CASE 
       WHEN  Content = 'N' THEN 0
       WHEN  Content = 'P' THEN 1
       WHEN  Content = 'K' THEN 2
       WHEN  Content = 'OC' THEN 3
       ELSE 4
     END
    )
```